# Sharepoint 2010 XML schemas

Tags: development, configuration, xml

When developing in Sharepoint I noticed you eventually end-up editing lots of XML files: `Feature.Template.xml`s, `Package.Template.xml`s etc.

Although VS is helpful with auto-completion, I don't really know what all elements represent so I'm looking for a complete reference. Could'n find one.

Where can I get the XML schema references for all types of XML I intercat with while developing SP solutions.

P.S. I'm looking for the 2010 schemas.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharePoint Schema References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539685.aspx)

> This section provides schema reference and related documentation,
>   including schemas for alert templates, solutions, features, upgrade
>   definitions, Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML), and BDC
>   schemas.

And if you are using VS 2010 this extension could be helpful:

[caml.net.intellisense](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/15055544-fda0-42db-a603-6dc32ed26fde/)